# Is there any way of backing up the ODBC drivers of a server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, odbc

I need to replicate the ODBC drivers from one environment to another located on other server, the one that has the drivers I want to backup is running **`Windows Server 2012 Datacenter`** and the other **`Windows Server 2016 Standard`** (in case it matters). The problem is I don't figure a way out to backup/restore lots of ODBC drivers that the projects hosted on these servers need to work properly.

Are the drivers listed on the tabs **`System DSN,`** **`User DSN`** and **`File DSN`** stored physically on any directory of the server?

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]

What would the best practice to replicate/backup all the drivers listed from one server to the other so that I do not need to recreate them manually?

I would appreciate if there were a way of automating it by means of PowerShell script or something alike.

Comment: A quick google search for `powershell dsn` reveals [Add-OdbcDsn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/add-odbcdsn?view=win10-ps) and [Get-OdbcDsn](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh771015(v=wps.630).aspx). I assume you already tried them?

Comment: I didn't figure a way of making a backup of the ODBC drivers. I would like to know it they are stored somewhere on the server disk and how to deal with replicating them. I work with databases, I'm not a shell programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export the DSN into a file:

```powershell
Get-OdbcDsn |Export-Clixml dsn.xml
```

Import it again

```powershell
Import-Clixml dsn.xml |Add-OdbcDsn
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot. I didn't even know how to start searching for it.